# Ripple Blackberry webworks 10 not loading javascript

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I am using `Ripple` plugin for Chrome to try out HTML5 app with webworks 10 sdk. I cannot seem to be able to download any external javascript, I tried to get

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://www.blackberry.com/app_includes/asdk/adBanner.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://media.admob.com/api/v1/google_mobile_app_ads.js"></script>
```

but neither works, it always says not able to load resource, get failed, etc. 
I have this in the config.xml

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://www.blackberry.com/"> 
       <feature id="blackberry.advertising" required="true" version="1.0.0" /> 
    </access> 
    <accesss subdomains="true" uri="http://media.admob.com" />
```

Any help would be appreciated. If there is any other better alternative and example of displaying ad in HTML5 and BlackBerry it'll be even better!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Chrome may be blocking your request.  I've had this issue in the past and resolved it by adding the following to my Chrome shortcut

```
-–allow-file-access-from-files
```

If you're using the localhost way of running Ripple, it should not have this issue at all.  We have a lot of documentation on our developer site you can reference as well @ http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_with_ripple_1866966_11.html